# Get items from a list by ids of another list

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry if question title is confusing, I have a Scenario where i have two class User and the Address.

```
public class User
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }

    public List<Address> address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

UserId is foreign key in class address, I have two List, List of user and List of address. Values for address in User is null, I want to get list of address for each user how can i achieve that? I know we can use foreach, but is there way to achieve this by linq? Below is sample code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var users = new List<User>();
        users.Add(new User { userId = 1, userName = "User 1" });
        users.Add(new User { userId = 2, userName = "User 2" });
        users.Add(new User { userId = 3, userName = "User 3" });
        users.Add(new User { userId = 4, userName = "User 4" });

        var address = new List<Address>();
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 1", City = "City 1", State = "State 1", UserId = 1 });
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 1 Dup", City = "City 1", State = "State 1", UserId = 1 });
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 2", City = "City 2", State = "State 2", UserId = 2 });
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 2 Dup", City = "City 2", State = "State 2", UserId = 2 });
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 3", City = "City 3", State = "State 3", UserId = 3 });
        address.Add(new Address { AddressLine = "Address 3 Dup", City = "City 3", State = "State 3", UserId = 3 });


    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note about your schema...I would consider modifying it if possible.  Storing a user ID with an address is a bad design.  What if two users live at the same address?  You should really have a many-to-many relationship, i.e. store a middle table with user ID and address ID.

Comment: This is just an example, As i cannot post my original code. It will be security breach so i kind off created similar dummy data. I agree this schema design is wrong.

Comment: LINQ also uses foreach. [check here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: Simple [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) will produce the desired correlation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Linq` version

```
List<User> result = users.Select(x => 
                         new User() { 
                            userId = x.userId, 
                            userName = x.userName, 
                            address = address.Where(y => y.UserId == x.userId).ToList() 
                         }).ToList();
```

---

imo more readable `foreach` version

```
foreach (User user in users)
    user.address = address.Where(y => y.UserId == user.userId).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sorry if this is silly question but if i use linq foreach instead select will it be slower or faster? Which is better Select or Linq Foreach? Something like this  users.ForEach(t => t.address = address.Where(a => a.UserId == t.userId).ToList());

Comment: It will be faster also note about this. It creates a copy of `User` so each change to each `User` in the derived list will not affect the actual `User`. That may or may not be what you want. Using `linq` is always slower.

Comment: You mean select would be faster? I am ok with changing actual User as that is the requirement.

Comment: @fubo as of now User has 4 rows and address has 100, At the max address will have 200 rows.

Comment: @ManishMakkad in that case it doesn't matter, this won't be the bottleneck - choose the code that is more readable to you

Comment: `foreach` is always faster, since the compiler can easily optimize that. `linq` creates a statemachine which may not be as fast, but unless you operate on billions of objects then it won't make a difference. We're talking small nanoseconds or something here. I would go for `Select` in this case though, just for readability.

Comment: @Bauss `foreach` or `Select` - it really doesn't matter. The critical (inefficient) part here is the inner `Where`, which makes the algorithm quadratic. That's why it's much better to use some of the relational operators (`GroupJoin` in this case as mentioned in the post comments).

Comment: @IvanStoev i think in case of 200 rows you can choose the better readable and less performant approach

Comment: @fubo Sure. As soon as you can be 100% sure they will never become more than that, can you ever know that :) The users of our programs do not care if the code is readable or not (of course it's good to be, but that's not the priority #1). This is not premature optimization, just performance culture :)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple with a `Select` and `Where`.

```
users = users.Select(u => { u.address = address.Where(a => a.UserId == u.userId).ToList(); return u; }).ToList();
```

A more readable version:

```
    users = users.Select(u =>
    {
        u.address = address.Where(a => a.UserId == u.userId).ToList();

        return u;
    }).ToList();
```